# Best way to organize Singleton class and a class that handles it in a project?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, software-design

Say I have a Settings class that I want to keep as a Singleton so all other services/classes etc. have access to the same thing.

```
public class Settings {
    private static Settings settings;

    public static Settings getInstance() {
        if (settings == null) {
            settings = new Settings();
        }
        return settings;
    }
    // More stuff
}
```

Now say I have a class with all static methods that handles the "Settings" data using this model.

```
public class SettingsManager() {
    public static Settings initSettings() {
        // Pull some data from the db
        String foo = db.getSomeData();
        return Settings.getInstance().setFoo(foo); // etc
    }
}
// Other static methods to update, etc.
```

I don't want to place the logic from the `SettingsManager` into `Settings` because it will no longer be a model since it'll contain logic to query the database etc.

Would it be a better approach to keep `SettingsManager` as an inner class of `Settings` or would it make more sense to make it its own class?

I want to think the latter, but if so, where would I place the `SettingsManager` class? What package? (com.myproject.models, com.myproject.somethingelse ?)

Comment: Your "singleton" creates a new `Settings()` object everytime since you never store it in `settings` - if you want that to work in a single line (but still not threadsafe) `return settings == null ? settings = new Settings() : settings;` - PS: would use `SettingsManager#getSettings()` to return a singleton value and probably hide the settings constructor (e.g. package private) so it's not used.

Comment: `getInstance()` doesn't seem like a method for a dumb "model" class (would make more sense for a different class to return an instance of it). But where it makes sense to put logic in it, it also makes sense to make it bear its own initialization logic.

Comment: Sorry was writing that on the fly. @zapl I'll fix it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are creating a new instance of Settings everytime you call Settings.getInstance(). Second, shouldn't be your SettingsManager the Singleton?
Otherwise Settings will be changed, everytime you call SettingsManager.initSettings(). How often will that be called?
(I wrote this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation yet to write a comment.)

Comment: I see, didn't think of it this way. I wanted the Settings model to be inaccessible. So you're saying make the SettingsManager a singleton that creates one Settings object? Only problem will be that the Settings model will be accessible but I guess thats fine :). Where to put the SettingsManager then?

Comment: You can give your Settings class "package visibility" by having it in the same package as your SettingsManager and removing the "public" qualifier.

Comment: I ended up keeping the model public and creating a singleton SettingsManager as you suggested. Thanks!